# Write clearcollect function to fetch data from post API

Tags: powerapps-collection

How to write the ClearCollect function to fetch the data from Post Api where headers are included.

```
header:
Content-Type:application/json
deviceId:ab
deviceType:A
deviceName: iphone 10
osVersion:1
ApiKey:0269b9130d957f4b9d5a9e1a008705fa
app_version:2.00

request:
{
"password":"nrla5650NR",
"ecode":"e6837",
"request":"login"
}
```

Please tell me how to write the Clear Collect function to get the data from data source of post Api where headers are added and giving the request, which i have already added from custom connector.

Answer (score 0):

You can only collect the response, you can't collect the headers. If your API returns no response, there's nothing to be collected. Although, if your request gets an answer, you can simply do `ClearCollect(ColName; API_Call)` and the response will be saved in the "ColName" collection